# People now say "back in 1985" or "way back in 1965" instead of just saying "in 1985" or "in 1965". Why this change?

Tags: past-tense, descriptive-grammar

Most native English speakers used to refer to a past time or date by saying something like "in 1936 this or that happened". Now people seem unable to refer to the past - however recent or ancient - without saying "back in", or "way back in". Has anybody else noticed this change? And it doesn't just refer to someone's age in relation to the event they're describing. It seems like a universal shift. I'd love to know your observations.

Comment: I can see no evidence in Google ngrams for say "back in 1920" vs "in 1920" that this claim is more than localised perception.

Comment: Google ngrams is about books and printed matter, and it doesn't show day to day speech trends, and what I'm referring to is definitely casual speech rather than written English. I've searched extensively too and I can't find it anywhere on Google, but it's more than a localised perception. Regardless of that way, have you noticed the shift Edwin?

Comment: "back in" emphasises it was a long time ago. Regardless, the claim is false. People still just say "in". Without any evidence this seems like a rant about something imaginary.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no evidence that the claim in the question is true.

Comment: People have been saying "back in {month, year, decade, century} " for a very long time. It's not new. There's no general "shift". People start using it when they grow older and  begin to feel the passage of time and  develop a sense of history.  You don't hear children using it. An age cohort of speakers may begin to use it.

Comment: I think @TimR's comment is basically saying what I said in my answer. And a wrong premise is not a reason to close a question: it provides a basis to say "that's [almost certainly] wrong and here's why."

Comment: It's existed for at least [half a century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/December,_1963_(Oh,_What_a_Night)).  How prevalent it was 50 years ago, or 49, I cannot say.  Google ngram viewer finds an instance of "back in the old days" in the Maryland constitutional convention of 1864.  But I've noticed a more general proliferation of unnecessary "back" (among other prepositions), as in "return it back" and "respond back" and probably some more subtle examples I can't call [back] to mind just now.

Comment: TimR is probably correct, and I feel the 'comment' section is the only place he can validly offer a useful response that he can't corroborate. But then the question itself needs supporting evidence.

Answer (score 2):

I dispute the basic premise of the question, which requires corroboration to support it.

However, it seems to me that "Back in..." serves to provide a contrast with the present, maybe even a touch of nostalgia, whereas the lone "in" is baldly factual. With a contrast and increasing amounts of nostalgia, we might have:

> Back in 1936 there was a single Jewish woman in the German Olympic team
> Back in 1936 there were lots of bees in Montana
> Back in my day we...

Stuart F has commented *"back in" emphasises it was a long time ago.* There may be a cut-off point after which "Back in" might be inappropriate; but again that would appear to depend on the contrast being made. It would quite reasonable to say

> Back in January we had gale-force winds most days
> Back in 2020 we could scarcely leave our houses

It's the element of contrast which "Back in" particularly brings.

I **suspect** that the OP's experience of differing trends in printed work and conversation is that printed work tends to be more formal, and "Back in" is less formal because it introduces redundancy. It's therefore more likely to occur in conversation. But I dispute the assertion that things have changed from a bald "in" to "back in"; if one is simply stating that fact that "in 1936 there was a single Jewish woman in the German Olympic team", the *back* is not needed at all.

Comment: "back in" can have the nuance of "things have really changed in the intervening time".  The change can be for the worse or for the better.

Comment: I think I mentioned contrast.

Comment: Yes, just adding "for the better" since you emphasized examples of nostalgia.  Though the Olympics example seemed out of place.